# Name resolver libraries for Linux

Tags: c, linux, resolver

Can someone guide me about what are the libraries available for the name resolution other than glibc's getaddrinfo for Linux.

Comment: If you tell us why you want something else (including what you don't like bout the glibc version, and what other features or things you a looking for), we might be able to help you better.

Comment: @joachimPileborg: Actually I didn't find anything wrong about glibc. I'm just looking for the alternatives to compare.